# Change/ rewrite value in the package.json via the terminal

Tags: json, node.js, terminal

i am using  'cat package.json'  to view the  json file in my terminal. 
Because I am testing different modules, I want to replace the main value so I can easily try different files as the entry point.
 : "main": "index.js",
like above  I rather change index.js via the command line. 
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use VIM (https://github.com/vim/vim) or Nano (https://www.nano-editor.org/).